# How to update a textfield based on other form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm writing a little database query app.

*What i'm trying to do:* Each time a checkbox is clicked, i'd like for a query that includes the selected fields to be generated and inserted into the textarea.

*The problem:* For some reason, with every click, its showing the query from the previous click event, not the current one.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="application container" ng-controller="OQB_Controller">

        <!-- top headr -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse shadow" role="navigation">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                Algebraix Database Client
            </a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!--<li><a href="" class="queries-clear">Clear Queries</a></li>-->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span> Load Data <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="btn-data-import-default">Default Data</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataImport">Custom Import</a></li>
                        <!-- <li class="divider"></li> -->
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="" class="queries-clear">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear Queries
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well form-group">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="option in options">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="included-{{option.included}}" value="{{option.value}}" ng-click="buildQuery()" ng-model="option.included"> {{option.text}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- right column -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form role="form" id="sparqlForm" method="POST" action="" class="form howblock">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--<label>Query</label>-->
                    <textarea type="text" name="query" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Write your SPARQL query here">{{query}}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Query" data-loading-text="Running Query..." />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

</div>
```

And in my controller, i am doing the following:

```
var OQB_Controller = function($scope) {
    console.log('OQB_CONTROLLER');

    $scope.query = 0;

    $scope.options = [
        { text: "checkbox1", value: "xyz123", included: false }
        ,{ text: "checkbox2", value: "abcRRR", included: false }
        ,{ text: "checkbox2", value: "abcRRR", included: false }
    ];

    $scope.buildQuery = function() {
        console.log('click');
        var lines = [];
        lines.push("SELECT *");
        lines.push("WHERE {");
        lines.push(" ?s ?p ?o .");
        for(var i = 0; i<$scope.options.length; i++) {
            var line = $scope.options[i];
            console.log( line.value, line.included, i );
            if( line.included ) {
                lines.push("  OPTIONAL { ?s "+line.value+" ?o } .");
            }
        }
        lines.push("}");
        lines.push("LIMIT 10");
        var _query = lines.join("\n");
        $scope.query = _query;
    };

};
```

To reiterate, every time the build query method is called, the state of the `included` booleans is from one click event prior. this has the symptoms of the classic javascript problem of the keyup vs keydown and the state of the event... however, i'm not sure if that is what is happening here.

is there a better way to do build the query (than what i'm currently doing) and populate the textarea based on the checked boxes?

Comment: would try switching  `ng-click` to `ng-change`. If that doesn't work, try wrapping code within `buidQuery` in `$timeout`

Comment: @charlietfl that worked. please create and answer with that in it, and I'll upvote it and accept it.

Comment: which one worked...guessing was `$timeout`

Comment: @charlietfl changing `ng-click` to `ng-change` was the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click` because it is more appropriate for this particular desired behavior. See the `ng-change` documentation below:

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated:
>
> if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
>   not changed if the input has continued to be invalid since the model
>   will stay null if the model is changed programmatically and not by a
>   change to the input value